# Error When Updating HikariCP with JTDS and Spring Boot 1.5

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hikaricp

---

APPLICATION FAILED TO START

---

Description:

Binding to target HikariDataSource (HikariPool-1) failed:

```
Property: spring.datasource.hikari.connectionTestQuery
Value: SELECT 1
Reason: Property 'connectionTestQuery' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: The configuration of the pool is sealed once started. Use HikariConfigMXBean for runtime changes.
```

Comment: Please share hikari bean definition here.

Comment: @AshishPatil i am not creating a bean for hikari, i have specified the hikari properties in the spring boot as below

spring.datasource.driver-class-name=net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.hikari.connection-test-query=SELECT 1
spring.datasource.hikari.data-source-properties.socketTimeout=300
spring.datasource.hikari.data-source-properties.loginTimeout=20
spring.datasource.hikari.minimumIdle=1
spring.datasource.hikari.maximumPoolSize=1
spring.datasource.hikari.idleTimeout=600000
spring.datasource.hikari.maxLifetime=18000
spring.datasource.hikari.connectionTimeout=3000

Comment: bean definition does not necessarily mean java bean. So  in your application property, you have `spring.datasource.hikari.connection-test-query=SELECT 1` which is not required and that is what I have mentioned in my answer. 
Remove this entry from property & if it works you can close question by accepting answer.

Comment: After Migrating the spring boot version to below

<parent>
    <groupId>com.accurate.boot</groupId>  
    <artifactId>accurate-spring-starter-parent</artifactId>
     <version>1.5.22.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After upgrading the application to the below version of the spring boot, the application started with no errors

```
<parent>
<groupId>com.accurate.boot</groupId>  
<artifactId>accurate-spring-starter-parent</artifactId>
 <version>1.5.22.RELEASE</version>
```

Answer (score 0):

As per Hikari [documentation](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP), you may not required to set this property if you use latest JDBC drivers. This property is for legacy JDBC drivers (<JDBC4).

You can try running your application without setting this property. Moreover, if still issue persists, please share hikari bean definition; I will update my answer based on that.